# how make visible and invisible Drawable Left on EditTextView?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, drawable

I have read many answers in Stack but none of them can't help me, so please don't mark it as Duplicate ,I have `EditText`, and I want to make visible drawable left when the length of inserted data in EditTextView become equals to 11.

Comment: What do you mean by *"I want to visible drawable left"*?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to visible/invisible drawable left on user typing then do like this:

```
EditText et = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.edt);
et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        if(editable.length() >= 11){
            // visible
            et.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.your_icon, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        else {
            // hide
            et.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) { }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) { }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setCompoundDrawables` method to do this:

```
Drawable img = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.add_more);
img.setBounds(0, 0, 60, 60);
edittext.setCompoundDrawables(img, null, null, null);

if (edittext.lenght == 11) {
    img.setVisible(false, false);
}
```

I hope it will help you!